# Ajax form submission is not working in joomla 2.5.9

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla2.5

I am having a registration form in my pop up window.. i need to show my server side errors in the popup window itself after the submission of the form. for this, i had used ajax. but the success message is getting into ajax success function and page is redirecting to other. plz help me to work my ajax function. here, i am posting my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#login-form").validate({
    //var formToken = jQuery(".form_token").val();

        submitHandler: function(form){
        var form_data = jQuery("#login-form").serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url:"index.php?option=com_users&task=registration.register&"+<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>+"=1",
            data:form_data,
            dataType:html,
            success:function(res){
            alert(res)
                if( res == 1 ){
                    jQuery("#form_msg").val(res);
                }
            }
        })
        }
    });
```

Plz reply me soon.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found the solution for my problem
http://extensions.bowthemes.com/bt-login.html
use this module.. this will help in creating registration using ajax in joomla 2.5.9
have fun :)